# How could I make a dash in a 2D pygame python program?

Tags: python, pygame

If the pygame program is just a basic entity you can move normally with arrow keys, how could i make it so that if space is pressed, based on the arrow key that was being held at the moment of pressing, a player dashes slightly to the specified direction? My idea is that when the space is pressed, program checks if other keys are being held down and based on that it rapidly increases the x and/or y coordinate and then stops at specific time, but I don't know how to make it stop as all of this is happening inside a main game loop. Any insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: You already described it. Store the time when the dash started and stop it after some dash time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.perf_counter`.

So for using that function you will need to import module `time`

```py
import time
```

And now you can store the value of `time.perf_counter` in a variable when space is pressed.

```py
import time

jumping = False
start_time = 0

while True:
    if ("space is pressed"):  # Replace condition with what you want
        jumping = True
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
    
    # Add your code here

    if jumping:
        # change of x, y and other jumping mechanism code here

    if jumping and time.perf_counter() - start_time > 1: # Replace 1 with the amount you want this if condition to trigger, also add value in seconds
        jumping = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your code is like, but this is how I'd go about it:

```
def dash(self):
    keys = pygame.keys.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and not self.dashing and self.jumping:
                     # ^^ Can be any key
        if self.facing_right:
            self.x += 20
        if self.facing_left:
            self.x -= 20
        self.dashing = True
```

Make sure that when you hit the ground it does `self.dashing = False` else you will be able to dash forever.

Just put this function in the `player class` if you are doing it OOP.

Else if you are not using classes, put it anywhere in the file and ***take out all `self.`.***